# Magento 2 not allowed Superscript(“®”,"™") with product name!

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.4, name

If we have to display product name with superscript tag like "®","™", Magento 2 doesn't support and it display as it is without parsing  tag.

For example, if we have to display product name `"Magento Allowed<sup>®</sup> Superscript"` :-

[image],

then from backend product section if we have directly add `"Magento Allowed<sup>®</sup> Superscript"` as product name:-

Then it will display **as it is** without parsing  on browser :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the Magento issue and to fixed this, please follow following four steps :-

**1- Define **global plugin** in di.xml file :-**

```
<type name="\Magento\Framework\Escaper">
        <plugin name="Escaper-Plugin"
                type="Waqar\Catalog\Plugin\Product\EscaperPlugin" disabled="false" sortOrder="0" />
    </type>
```

**2- EscaperPlugin.php :-**

```
<?php

namespace Waqar\Catalog\Plugin\Product;

use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Waqar\Catalog\Helper\Config as ConfigHelper;

class EscaperPlugin
{
    const ALLOWED_SUPERSCRIPT_TAG = ['sup'];
    const SUPERSCRIPT_TAG = '<sup>';

     /**
     * @var ConfigHelper
     */
    protected $configHelper;

    /**
     * @param ConfigHelper $configHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        ConfigHelper $configHelper
    ) {
        $this->configHelper = $configHelper;
    }

    public function beforeEscapeHtml(
        Escaper $subject,
        $data,
        $allowedTags = null
    ) {
        if ($this->configHelper->superScriptConfigAllowed() && $this->strDataContainsSuperScript($data)) {
            $allowedTags = $this->getAllowedTags($allowedTags);
        }

        return [$data, $allowedTags];
    }

    /**
     * Function return if data type is string and it contains superscipt tag
     *
     * @return boolean
     */

    public function strDataContainsSuperScript($data): bool
    {
        if (is_string($data) && strpos($data, self::SUPERSCRIPT_TAG) !== false) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * return allowed tags
     *
     * @return array
     */

    public function getAllowedTags($allowedTags)
    {
        if ($allowedTags == null) {
            $allowed_tags = self::ALLOWED_SUPERSCRIPT_TAG;
        } else if (is_array($allowedTags)) {
            $allowed_tags = array_merge($allowedTags, self::ALLOWED_SUPERSCRIPT_TAG);
        }

        return $allowed_tags;
    }
}
```

**3-Config.php :-**

```
<?php

namespace Waqar\Catalog\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

/**
 * Class Config
 * @package Waqar\Catalog\Helper
 */
class Config extends AbstractHelper
{
    /** @var string  */
    const ALLOWED_SUPERSCRIPT_TAG_CONFIG_PATH = 'catalog/catalog_superscript_group/allowed_superscript_with_product_name';

    /** @var StoreManagerInterface  */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * Config constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Function return if current website allowed superscript with product name
     *
     * @return boolean
     */

    public function superScriptConfigAllowed(): bool
    {
        $website_id = $this->getWebsiteId();

        $result = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::ALLOWED_SUPERSCRIPT_TAG_CONFIG_PATH,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
            $website_id
        );

        return (bool) $result;
    }

    /**
     * return current website id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function getWebsiteId()
    {
        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();

        return $store->getWebsiteId();
    }
}
```

**4-adminhtml/system.xml :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="catalog" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40   " showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                 showInStore="1">
            <group id="catalog_superscript_group" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2000" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label><![CDATA[Allow Superscript with Product Name]]></label>
                <field id="allowed_superscript_with_product_name" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Allow Superscript with Product Name</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <comment>Allow Superscript like ®,™ with Product Name</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
    </system>
</config>
```